# How to generate multiple mousedown events with overlapping objects in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

I have several (somewhat) overlapping `div`s, and if the user clicks on part of the overlap, I want a `mousedown` event (or any similar callback) for *each* `div` that's below the mouse coordinates.

The standard way, of course, only generates a callback for the topmost `div`. Is this possible?

Comment: The only way that comes to mind would be to look for all divs on the page and check if any part of them is within the boundaries of the mouse click, but that would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. But isn't that how the mousedown event must work anyways?

Comment: I agree with Dans comment, that's the only way i can think of doing it too. Some info on event capture / bubble here http://is.gd/1fQbE. I guess you could store each divs co-ords in an object(update them if they move) and loop through them that way, could speed things up rather than loping through all the divs and finding the co-ords each time. Thats how i would approach it i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up drawing a big (empty) div on top of everything, storing each smaller guy's position, and then handling the `mousedown` event from the big div and distributing it to the little ones.

It's a little better than iterating through all divs on the page because there's some structure to where they are, so the lookup is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use motionbox
http://github.com/tobowers/motionbox-eventhandler